# How to close and reopen an iframe with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Was wondering if someone can help me figure out the way to close and   reopen an iframe with the same button.

[image]

Right now the iframe is displayed aswell as the button.

Comment: I got the script from trying to look it up.

Comment: Please do not use a screenshot to share your source code. Stackoverflow allows you to create a snippet or post your source code within your question. Please edit your question to make it easier to work with. Thank you. **Edit:** Also I cannot see a button to open/close any iframe so please ensure you explain where those can be found within your source code `#more` & `#espn` do not appear to exist. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To improve this question show us what you have done. Show source code and describe what it is doing and what you need it to do. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're referring to here, but to hide and unhide the iframe with one button, you can use:

```
var iframeHidden = false;
function hideIframe(id) {
    if (!statusVar) {
        document.getElementById(id).hidden = "true";
        iframeHidden = true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(id).removeAttribute("hidden")
        iframeHidden = false;
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: `iframeHidden` should be a boolean value (`true` or `false`) describing whether or not the element is currently hidden.
Then, use `hideIframe("youtube")` to hide and unhide the frame with the same button. You'll have to make an [event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp). For instance:

```
document.getElementById("ytbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {hideIframe("youtube");}, false)
```